# How to extract a keyword from a string in Regex

Tags: regex

*For example*: I want to extract the variable `id` from this string: `validateId(id, name) && id=="123"`. However, I do not want to extract the word `id` from other places, such as in this case in `validateId`. Therefore, the result in this case would be: `validateId(id, name) && id=="123"`
I have tried matching on the opening brackets in `validateId(` however I am not managing to extract exactly what I need.

Note: `id` is just an example, I want to be able to accept any form of keywords. However, I can then change the regex accordingly to the keyword that I want.

Comment: This might enough https://regex101.com/r/gT8wK5/1328

Comment: Apologies if it was not clear. I have edited in the result that I am expecting.

Comment: perhaps try using a word boundary, something like [so](https://regex101.com/r/gT8wK5/1329)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the keywords that you want to extract are always found in the same pattern. In this example I've added another.

```
test_str = '''validateId(id, name) && id=="123"
              ParameterValue(Test, name) && Test=="123"'''
```

Match the pattern of the provided test string. This will find `ìd` and `test`.

```
reg_keyword = '(?<=\()(\w+)|(?<=&&\s)(\w+)'
```

`re.findall` returns a tuple in this case, where we are removing empty values and returning a list.

```
keyword = [k[0] for k in re.findall(reg_keyword, test_str) if len(k[0])>1]
```

Output

```
['id', 'Test']
```